# ServiceStack InMemoryVirtualPathProvider for Razor - GetViewPage null

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I tested this with the default out of the box implementation and GetViewPage retrieves the view from the file system without a problem.

I swapped out the RazorFormat's VirtualFileSource for the inmemory one:

```
 Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat() {
            VirtualFileSources = new InMemoryVirtualPathProvider(this),
  });
```

In the service I'm writing a view if it doesn't exist:

```
 var helloView = razor.GetViewPage(email.BlastId.ToString());
 if (helloView==null)
 {
   ((InMemoryVirtualPathProvider)razor.VirtualFileSources)
   .WriteFile("~/views/"+email.BlastId + ".cshtml", email.Blast);
   // .WriteFile(email.BlastId + ".cshtml", email.Blast);  doesn't work
 }
 helloView = razor.GetViewPage(email.BlastId.ToString());
 //helloView is always null
```

I've confirmed that the RazorFormat's VirtualFileSource has the file, the GetViewPage just doesn't retrieve it.

Screenshot of the file located in the VirtualFileSource: https://db.tt/8oirKd9Msi

Furthermore this returns true: `razor.VirtualFileSources.FileExists("~/views/"+email.BlastId + ".cshtml")` I've tried it without the views folder/etc.  It doesn't seem to make an impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RazorFormat` loads compiled views on Startup, so the view needs to exist in the `VirtualFileSources` before `RazorFormat` is registered in order for it to be available with `GetViewPage()`.

To add a file after RazorFormat has loaded, you need to call `AddPage()` after it's written to the Virtual File System, e.g:

```
razorFormat.VirtualFileSources.WriteFile(filePath, contents);
var razorView = razorFormat.AddPage(filePath);
```

If you only wanted to create a temporary Razor View you can call `CreatePage()` to create the view:

```
var razorView = razorFormat.CreatePage(razorHtml);
```

And render it with:

```
razorFormat.RenderToHtml(razorView, model);
```

Or if both the Razor Page and model is temporary, it can be condensed in the 1-liner:

```
var html = razorFormat.CreateAndRenderToHtml(razorHtml, model);
```

#### Working Example

```
const string template = "This is my sample view, Hello @Model.Name!";

RazorFormat.VirtualFileSources.WriteFile("/Views/simple.cshtml", template);
var addedView = RazorFormat.AddPage("/Views/simple.cshtml");
var viewPage = RazorFormat.GetViewPage("simple"); //addedView == viewPage

var html = RazorFormat.RenderToHtml(viewPage, new { Name = "World" });

html.Print(); //= "This is my sample view, Hello World!"
```

Comment: After adding the page (first example) how do I retrieve it again?  GetViewPage returns null still?

Comment: @lucuma Adding the page should return the page?

Comment: That is correct, it does, but if I need to send an email to 1000 employees I wanted to add it one time and just retrieve it on the next 999.  What is the point of `AddPage` ?

Comment: It adds the compiled page, you can reuse the razorView instance returned with different models to generate html for each model. Don't use add `~/` when adding the page.

Comment: I understand I can cache the `razorView` that is returned from AddPage myself which is what I think you are saying I need to do.  The GetViewPage never returns it after adding it.

Comment: @lucuma I've added a [working test example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/e751df1ed401d55710ca7229965a2474f489c216)

Comment: @lucuma `AddPage` is on `RazorFormat` and there are [WriteFile extension methods on IVirtualPathProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/VirtualPath/VirtualPathProviderExtensions.cs)

Comment: I removed my last comment (tired).  I removed the /views from the path and I think that caused it to not find it on the getviewpage.  Your example works in my project.  Very much appreciate your help and answers.